# Recyclerview will not loading entire collection into grid from firebase and Picasso does not load any pictures

Tags: android, firebase, gridview, android-recyclerview, picasso

i am having 2 issues:

My recycler is successfully getting the names of the categories i have in firebase firestore but:

1 it is not loading the entire collection unless i change the span count to match exactly the same number of items.

2 Picasso is failing to load the pictures attached to the collections.

i have tried changing the height of the recycler and cardviews but it's not working. the only thing that seems to work is to change the span count but then everything gets squashed up because it is all stuck in 1 row.

regarding the image loading I've tried other solution from other questions but still nothing. the only error I'm getting in the logs is  "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

My home fragment

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.buzzamaid.Adapter.ExtrasAdapter;
import com.example.buzzamaid.Common.SpacesItemDecoration;
import com.example.buzzamaid.Interface.BathroomsLoadListener;
import com.example.buzzamaid.Interface.ExtraServicesLoadListerner;
import com.example.buzzamaid.Model.Extras;
import com.example.buzzamaid.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.Unbinder;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;

public class HomeDetailsFragment  extends Fragment implements BathroomsLoadListener, ExtraServicesLoadListerner {

    //Variable
    CollectionReference bedroomsRef;
    CollectionReference bathroomsRef;
   CollectionReference extrasRef;


    BathroomsLoadListener bathroomsLoadListener;
    HomeDetailsFragment bedroomsLoadListener;
    ExtraServicesLoadListerner extraServicesLoadListerner;


    @BindView(R.id.spinner)
    MaterialSpinner spinner;

    @BindView(R.id.spinner_bedrooms)
    MaterialSpinner spinner_bedrooms;


    @BindView(R.id.recycler_bedrooms)
    RecyclerView recycler_bedrooms;

    @BindView(R.id.extra_services_recycler)
    RecyclerView extra_services_recycler;


    Unbinder unbinder;
    AlertDialog dialog;




    static HomeDetailsFragment instance;

    public  static HomeDetailsFragment getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new HomeDetailsFragment();
        return instance;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bathroomsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("AllServices/HomeCleaning/Bathrooms");
        bedroomsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("AllServices/HomeCleaning/Bedrooms");



        bathroomsLoadListener = this;
        bedroomsLoadListener = this;
        extraServicesLoadListerner = this;

        dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(getActivity()).build();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

       View itemView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_details,container,false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);

        initView();
        LoadBathrooms();
        LoadBedrooms();


        return itemView;


    }

    private void initView() {
        extra_services_recycler.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(4));
        extra_services_recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

    }


    private void LoadBedrooms() {
        bedroomsRef.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add("Select number of bedrooms");
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult())
                                list.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                            bedroomsLoadListener.onBedroomLoadListenerSuccess(list);
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                bedroomsLoadListener.onBedroomLoadListenerFailed(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void onBedroomLoadListenerSuccess(List<String> numberbedroomList) {
        spinner_bedrooms.setItems(numberbedroomList);
        spinner_bedrooms.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, Object item) {
                if (position  > 0)
                {
                    loadExtraServices(item.toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadExtraServices(String extrasNames) {
        dialog.show();

        extrasRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("AllServices/HomeCleaning/ExtraServices");

        extrasRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                List<Extras> list = new ArrayList<>();
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult())
                        list.add(documentSnapshot.toObject(Extras.class));
                    extraServicesLoadListerner.onExtraServicesLoadListenerSuccess(list);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                extraServicesLoadListerner.onExtraServicesLoadListenerFailed(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void onBedroomLoadListenerFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    private void LoadBathrooms() {
        bathroomsRef.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                           List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                           list.add("Select number of bathrooms");
                           for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult())
                               list.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                           bathroomsLoadListener.onBathroomLoadListenerSuccess(list);
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              bathroomsLoadListener.onBathroomLoadListenerFailed(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onBathroomLoadListenerSuccess(List<String> numberbathroomsList) {
spinner.setItems(numberbathroomsList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBathroomLoadListenerFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    @Override
    public void onExtraServicesLoadListenerSuccess(List<Extras> ExtrasList) {
        ExtrasAdapter adapter = new ExtrasAdapter(getActivity(),ExtrasList);
        extra_services_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onExtraServicesLoadListenerFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.buzzamaid.Model.Extras;
import com.example.buzzamaid.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ExtrasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExtrasAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    TextView extra_services_title;
    ImageView extra_services_image;

    Context context;
    List<Extras> extrasList;

    public ExtrasAdapter(Context context, List<Extras> extrasList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.extrasList = extrasList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.extra_services_card,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
       myViewHolder.extra_services_title.setText(extrasList.get(i).getName());
       Picasso.get().load(extrasList.get(i).getImage()).into(extra_services_image);





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return extrasList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView extra_services_title;
        ImageView extra_services_image;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            extra_services_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.extra_services_title);
            extra_services_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.extra_services_image);
        }
    }
}
```

My consturctors and getter

```
public class Extras {
    private String name,image;
    private int price;


    public Extras() {
    }

    public Extras(String name, String image, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/abel_regular"/>

    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_bedrooms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abel_regular"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_bedrooms"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/extra_services_recycler"
        />



</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
database structure
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMZ4s.png)

i expect for the images to be loaded into the views and for the entire collection to be loaded not just the Span count.

Comment: Show us your database structure.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for responding. I've attached my database structure at the bottom

Comment: Your code looks good to me but what do you mean through "change the span count"? Where in your code are you doing this? If you get the url of the image from a document and put it in a browser is the image displayed?

Comment: im referring to this section
`private void initView() {
        extra_services_recycler.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(4));
        extra_services_recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), **3**));`

its only showing 3 views as the same number of columns instead of have 3 columns and displaying everything in the database and yes the links do display  images.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the reason the recycler wasn't showing all the cardview was because i had set the card template to match parent width and height instead of wrap content. and forgotten the "myviewadapter" into.(myviewadapter.Destination) in the picasso)